# jQuery AppendTo

Tags: jquery, appendto

I'm not sure why this jQuery is outputting malformed HTML:

```
<img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5300/5459333519_0bfb0763b0_m.jpg">
```

From this code:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=59597329@N08&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        $("<img>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#mac");
    });
});
```

`#mac` is the div to hold the images

Can anyone make sense of this?

Comment: Do you mean "malformed XHTML"?

Comment: it is working for me. see http://jsfiddle.net/rcrathore/v3JUy/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That HTML is perfectly valid. (For XHTML you'd have to use a self-closing element.)

But **that doesn't matter**, because by the time jQuery is modifying things, it's interacting with the DOM (the markup part of things is pretty much over, except that jQuery uses `innerHTML` when it can under-the-covers). So you won't see the result as markup except in tools (like Firebug) that will show you DOM structures as HTML strings. **If** you're using an XHTML document, perhaps whatever tool you're using isn't following XHTML convention for display purposes, but that's just a display problem, not an actual problem with the page.

Think of it this way: Markup is like a string literal in your source code; the DOM is like the actual string at runtime. Debuggers will show you a string's contents at runtime, usually using similar notation to string literals (though that varies); similarly, tools like Firebug and Chrome's dev tools, etc., show you DOM structures using markup notation. But that's just a display thing in the tool.

Comment: Agreed--markup validity is a concern when creating markup for a browser to parse into a DOM tree. Viewing "generated source" or something like the HTML tab of Firebug and seeing what you consider to be invalid is not a concern at all. It's just that programs representation of what exists in memory.

Answer (score 0):

It's not jQuerys `.appendTo` which causes the "problem". At snippet like this:

```
var bar = document.createElement('img');
    bar.setAttribute('src', 'http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5300/5459333519_0bfb0763b0_m.jpg');
    document.body.insertBefore(bar, document.body.firstChild);
```

will also create an `<img>` node without a closing `</img>`. Anyway this is absolutly fine and valid in all browsers. If some XHTML validation does complain about this, you may ignore it gracefully.

Comment: The "closing" tag is a *markup* concept. This is the DOM we're interacting with, not markup. Whatever's showing you markup for that is a tool that's reading the DOM and *rendering* it as markup, which is something else entirely.

Comment: @T.J.: agreed. Anyway, most tags must have a closing tag or `/>` by specification. It's also a difference if your document is `HTML` or `XML` marked when a browser does parse it. For instance, a `<script`> tag without a closing tag is totally fine in XML, but will break your code in HTML parsing.

Comment: My point is that all of this is happening after the parsing of the page is complete; markup no longer applies (except when you're getting/setting `innerHTML`), we're manipulating the DOM. If you're seeing markup, you're just seeing what a tool is generating when you're looking at the DOM structure, just like a debugger will show you a string's contents using notation similar to string literals. Speaking of markup, though, the OP hasn't said he's using XHTML, and the `/>` thing is *invalid* in HTML for void elements like `img`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#elements-0

Comment: Sorry, my comment that `/>` is invalid in HTML with void elements like `img` is wrong: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags It's allowed, it's just ignored if it's there.